# BigQuery bq SSL issue

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery job running periodically. It was running fine so far. Now I am getting the following error. And when I directly tried executing the `bq` commands in the terminal it does not result in the same error response consistently. Sometimes it works fine.

The bash command used is:

```sh
bq query --project_id=$BQ_PROJECT_ID --nouse_legacy_sql --format=json --quiet $MAX_TIME_QUERY
```

And it raises the following error:

> BigQuery error in query operation: Cannot contact server. Please try again.
>       Traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bigquery_client.py", line 681, in BuildApiClient
>       _, discovery_document = http.request(discovery_url)
>       File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client_4_0/transport.py", line 160, in new_request
>       credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)
>       File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client_4_0/client.py", line 762, in _refresh
>       self._do_refresh_request(http)
>       File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client_4_0/client.py", line 781, in _do_refresh_request
>       body=body, headers=headers)
>       File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client_4_0/transport.py", line 283, in request
>       connection_type=connection_type)
>       File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1626, in request
>       (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
>       File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1368, in _request
>       (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
>       File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1288, in _conn_request
>       conn.connect()
>       File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1082, in connect
>       raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
>       SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)

I am using this within docker container (`google/cloud-sdk:206.0.0-alpine`). Also the same container when run on my mac laptop it works fine. When I check the same on a linux server it fails.

Comment: SSL errors normally indicate that some kind of proxy is interfering.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Why is it not consistently resulting in error? It does work sometime if I run multiple times. Also why does commands within docker container work on my mac but not on linux server.

Comment: I was able to resolve this "certificate verify failed" issue after uninstalling the httplib2 package

Comment: @Christopher but it is not consistent, the issue I am facing. Also it works on my mac using the google cloud sdk docker container. Any links to the issue you faced.

Comment: @premkumar I did not create an SO post for my issue. The issue happened to me whenever I try to run any python script on my Cloud Shell (it got messed up probably). I tried to search for answers everywhere on how to resolve the error "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" but in the end I did uninstall the package and the issue got resolved.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard any suggestions on how to identify or fix the issue?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to `google/cloud-sdk:250.0.0-alpine` version resolved the problem. I did not figure out the root cause for this problem but upgrading helped to fix it.